# Highstocks - how to detect when zoom button is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I've been googling around and combing through the [Highstock API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events) but can't seem to find an event listener for when a zoom button is pressed.

For example in [this example](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/) when the user clicks one of the zoom buttons in the upper left, I'd like to fire an event, expectedly with the index of the button being clicked.

Answer (score 0):

The buttons can be accessed from the `chart` object as `.rangeSelector.buttons`.  So something like this would create an additional click handler on them:

```
var thoseButts = Highcharts.charts[0].rangeSelector.buttons;
for (var i = 0; i < thoseButts.length; i++){
    $(thoseButts[i].element).click({idx: i},function(event){
        alert('Index: ' + event.data.idx);
    });
}
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NrTM4/).

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution

```
xAxis: {
    events: {
        setExtremes: function(e) {
            console.log(this);
            if(typeof(e.rangeSelectorButton)!== 'undefined')
            {
              alert('count: '+e.rangeSelectorButton.count + 'text: ' +e.rangeSelectorButton.text + ' type:' + e.rangeSelectorButton.type);
            }
        }
    }
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/E6GHC/1/